# How to activate or call a component register method when page is loading using knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

In my project I need to display a component while page is loading. Now it is loading on a button click.

[image]

When we click on "+Add a Phone number" button new component will be registered and displayed.

But what is my intention is to display like this when page is loading,

[image]

Here is my code that should be changed,

[image]

Comment: Please add the code as actual code and not an image.

Comment: Screenshot is not the best way to share your code. Always try to paste actual code.

Comment: Also, please add (at least) the `$component.addPhone` function from your JavaScript.

Comment: hi, as i understand you will need requirejs or any amd loader

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you have an observableArray `phones`. Why not just initialize that with an empty object?